# 3 interviews..job offer..clear background check...and no call?

Tags: job-offer, background-check

I have been interviewing this past month for a 3 month paid internship this summer. After a phone interview, I did 2 in-person interviews. Almost 2 weeks later on a Friday, HR finally calls me and tells me I got the position and to let them know by Monday. On Monday (May 12), I kindly accept the position. HR lady says "wonderful" and starts the background check and tells me she'll confirm my June 2nd start date upon clearing of background check. They used a 3rd party and when I filled out the form I selected to have the results emailed to me as well. By Thursday morning (May 15), the check was complete and clear... I even double checked with the 3rd party company.

It is now Tuesday (may 20) and HR have not returned my call or email about a completed background check and start date. Even more strangely, the internship is relisted on the careers section of their site? Perhaps they could be looking for an extra intern but still this makes no sense to me. Why they wouldn't get back to me at all, especially when they wanted me to start June 2nd?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations or agreements that are company-specific and don't have universally applicable answers.

Comment: There is not really a problem for us to solve here.  You can either wait to hear back or you can start looking for a new position... actually you can even do both.

Comment: Don't read into the fact there is another position posted.  Your position is only 3 months.  It took at least 30 days to get you.  This means they continously bring in new people just like yourself.  I personally would keep checking with the HR department, if you have another person in your rolodex at the company I would contact that person, its strange but the person could be on vaction or sick ( end of school, summer, ect ).

Answer (score 5):

How do you know the HR person that is to contact you didn't take a week of vacation that started May 14? There is nearly 2 weeks till June 2 and so there is still plenty of time to send e-mails would be how I'd see it. Alternatively, the HR person may have had the flu and been out of the office for the past week possibly.

If you aren't getting the e-mail within 2 business days of June 2, you may have something. Otherwise, I'd suspect you may be jumping the gun here a bit.

While the 3rd party's check was done Thursday morning, how do you know there aren't work for the company in terms of reading it through, filing it properly and other stuff?